# Queries with different time intervals to server from Service

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

I am using a Service to connect myself to a Server through Socket. What I want to achieve is this:
I need to keep on checking whether the phone is connected to the internet or not, if it is, the connection to the server is built and queries can be made. and when it isn't the socket is closed.
My problems lies here: Some of my queries should be made only once, other every two seconds and the last ones should be made every X minutes.

The queries that should be called only once aren't a problem, however I don't know how to deal with the other two. So far I call in the onStartCommand of the service a Thread. The call is repeated through a timer every two seconds. This deals with the first type of query but if I were to call another Thread inside the ConnectSocket thread for the queries that needs to be called every X minutes, it wouldn't work anymore.

I'd appreciate any help I can get !

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Thread thread = new Thread(new ConnectSocket());
                        thread.start();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 2000);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

```
class ConnectSocket implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (isConnectedToInternet()) {
                if (socket == null || socket.isClosed()) {
                    try {
                        connectToServer();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                sendMessageConnected();
                
                Thread pullThread = new Thread(new PullCowData());
                pullThread.start();

            } else {
                if (!socket.isClosed()) {
                    closeConnection();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [WorkManager](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager&ved=2ahUKEwjN_KSwiabwAhUohv0HHZpsClYQFnoECAcQAg&usg=AOvVaw0wnSqlHn6Imcu91TmoP5HB)
It has been designed specifically to schedule tasks on Android.